# configure new nodes to Hadoop cluster [/etc/hosts]

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hostname

I have a running hadoop cluster of 6 nodes [1 master and 5 slave nodes]. I made an snapshot image of a slave node and created a new node from this image.

I login to each ndoe, and manually update /etc/hosts file on all the Hadoop nodes in my cluster with the information of the new node.

This approach might be feasible for a smaller cluster. With a larger cluster, this approach would not work at all, I know.

I am tired of updating the new node info[ip-address  host-name] in /etc/hosts file of all the nodes manually. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Are you using any specific cloud environment like AWS, OpenStack ?

Comment: My Hadoop cluster is setup on top of OpenStack

Comment: One option would be to use [userdata](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/inserting_userdata.html) which allows to execute script with [cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) based systems. [Ticket](https://answers.launchpad.net/nova/+question/174023) related to executing script on bootup.

If you don't want to script I guess you have to setup your own DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OpenStack is configured and managed by admin. I have no control on it. I am accessing it via horizon interface. Could you please explain your idea in this context?

Comment: In that case I guess you can prepare an image with a script enabled to run during instance boot. For *nix flavors, add a script in init.d directory and use `chkconfig` to start the script at boot-up which would configure your `/etc/hosts`. Another generic solution would be to use an automation framework like puppet, chef to configure your instances.